# Custom Failure Handler for withFailureHandler - Google Apps Script

Tags: error-handling, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get more information for when `google.script.run` fails. I know that I can get a basic error handling callback function to give me the error message with something like this:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(handleError).getMe();
```

Where `handleError` gets an argument passed in for the error message.

```
function handleError(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

However, if I wanted to created a custom error handler that provided the location of where the exception was being thrown, I could use a custom function on `withFailureHandler`, like this:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function () {
  showError(error, 'getMe'); 
}).getMe();
```

With this method I'm stumped with one issue. How do I capture the error message to pass to my `showError()` error handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the error parameter to your anonymous function.

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function (error) {
  showError(error, 'getMe'); 
}).getMe();
```

Answer (score 1):

An errorHandler receives the error event from an exception that's *thrown* on the server. To pass a custom message, have your server side code do something like this:

```
...
if (errDetected) {
  throw new error("Custom message")
}
...
```