# Google App Script custom error on .withFailureHandler

Tags: google-sheets-api

I would like to throw a custom error in a function called with google.script.run from code.gs so I could display adequate information in a side bar. So far I've tested the following code with no luck:

code.gs

```
function UserException(type, text) {
  this.type = type;
  this.text = text;
  //this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
}
UserException.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
UserException.prototype.constructor = UserException;

function assignRangeToTechnician(technician)
{       
   if(technician!=null)
   {
    //some code 
   }else
    throw new UserException("Error","Technician was not selected");
}
```

sidebar.html

```
...
<script>
function btnSelectTech()
{
  google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(rangeSelected)
   .withFailureHandler(techniciansMessage)
   .assignRangeToTechnician(document.getElementById('selectTechnician').value);
}

function techniciansMessage(Message)
{     
  var outputMessage = document.getElementById('message');

  //here is where I log the Message value
  google.script.run.myLog("In techniciansMessage() - Message: " + Message);

  if (Message == null)
   outputMessage.innerHTML = "<p style='color:red;'>Error occured</p>";
  else
    if (Message.type == "Error")        
      outputMessage.innerHTML = "<p style='color:red;'>" + Message.text + "</p>";
    else if (Message.type == "Message")
      outputMessage.innerHTML = "<p style='color:#f3f3f3;'>" + Message.text + "</p>";
} 
</script>
...
```

When I run the code the .withFailureHandler is called but the `Message` doesn't hold the proper value. When I log that message I read "Error: " as a content of a 'Message' parameter.

Could you please help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066589/custom-failure-handler-for-withfailurehandler-google-apps-script). Try adding an error parameter to your function. Example:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function (error) {
  showError(error, 'getMe'); 
}).getMe();
```

Additional reference which might help: https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/blob/master/translate/Sidebar.js.html